# ROS2 Custom Messages Build Failed with InvalidFieldDefinition

Tags: ros2

I got an error with the following message when building a package with custom ROS2 Message.

```
rosidl_adapter.parser.InvalidFieldDefinition: geometry_msgs/Twist
```

I'm creating a new ROS2 Package to provide definitions of my custom message type like this:

```
src/msgs
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── msg
│   └── TwistAccel.msg
└── package.xml
```

Where my custom message defined like this:

TwistAccel.msg

```
geometry_msgs/Twist
geometry_msgs/Accel
```

According to the documents of ROS2 Foxy, I modified the `CMakeLists.txt` and `package.xml` like this:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(msgs)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)


rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/TwistAccel.msg"
)


if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

package.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>msgs</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="charlie@todo.todo">charlie</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>
  <build_depend>rosidl_default_generators</build_depend>

  <exec_depend>rosidl_default_runtime</exec_depend>

  <member_of_group>rosidl_interface_packages</member_of_group>

  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```

Then I run the `colcon build --packages-select msgs` command to build this package. However, I got the error mentioned before.

I have also tried modifying the `TwistAccel.msg` content from `geometry_msgs/xxx` to `geometry_msgs/msg/xxx`, but it still raises the same `InvalidFieldDefinition` to that.

I guess I'm missing something in the CMakeLists.txt or in package.xml. But I don't know what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the dependencies for your custom message(s). Since you are trying to use `geometry_msgs` within your custom message you should specify that in CmakeLists.txt.

Please refer to a project i did recently, you can find example on how to build custom message in ROS2 ; https://github.com/NMBURobotics/ros2_python_demos

Have a look at; `ros2_demo_custom_msgs`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks very much to @fet.atas. Although I think the dependencies issue is not the problems since I added `find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)` in my `CMakeLists.txt` and `<depend>geometry_msgs</depend>` in my `package.xml`, I did find my answer in the demo provided in his answer.

The problem is in the `.msgs` file, I didn't add the member's name in the custom message. Every members in the custom message should be added like this:

```
<message type> <message_name>
```

In my case, the correct format should be:

```
geometry_msgs/Twist twist
geometry_msgs/Accel accel
```

Then the `colcon build` command should finished with success message.

I hope this answer will be helpful to anyone with the same problem.

Comment: I dont think it is fair to write another answer based on a provided answer and accept that.

Comment: @fet.atas I'm sorry to make you feel this way, but I didn't mean to. 
Since my question itself stems from my carelessness, I hope visitors will not be confused because the reasons for the questions mentioned in your answer are not consistent with the actual ones. 
But I did find the problem after browsing the sample code you provided. 
I have set your answer to accept, but I would also like to remind other visitors that the actual problem is in my .msg definition, not in CMakLists.txt or package.xml. 
I would like to express my most sincere thanks to you again.